# f(x, y) function approximation

Tags: language-agnostic

I have a f(x, y) = z function (table-defined on uniform grid) and need to approximate it; this function is smooth. Approximation results must be as close to original as possible, derivatives are less important. Function domain is rectangular.
Suggest approaches to solve this task plz.

UPD I need **approximation**, not interpolation.
UPD2 Shape of this function is quite similar to earth surface
UPD3 My main task is to describe surface with smaller count of points, while retaining it's shape as close to original as possible.

Comment: can you elaborate on the problem domain and also the shape of the function more?

Comment: @awoodland: I think we can assume that the domain is a rectangle.

Comment: I meant the problem domain itself, not the domain of the function. Often certain function fitting problems in specific areas have common solutions that are picked more frequently for problems arising in one area than another.

Comment: @awoodland: good point. Let us get feedback from the OP then.

Comment: @user536232: Please describe your problem in a more specific way. What do you mean by "approximation" ? Do you want speed ? If accuracy is important to you, why don't you want interpolation ?

Comment: @Alexandre C., approximation is a well-known term, you can find it in Wiki.My main task is to describe surface with smaller count of points, while retaining it's shape as close to original as possible.

Comment: @user536232: sure. You should have precised it this way in your original post, because what first comes to mind when seeing 'uniform grid' is *really* interpolation. Especially since it is not obvious that you're willing to throw information away.

Comment: @user536232 "Mesh simplification" might even be appropriate here if "throwing away" is particularly important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be inclined to suggest NURBS approximations for this. You can make an approximate fit in a "least squares" sense. See for example *The NURBS book (Piegl and Tyler, 1997), §9.4.3*. In terms of freely available implementations I believe [NURBS++](http://libnurbs.sourceforge.net/) has an implementation of this algorithm (be sure to check the patch tracker before trying to make it compile with any modern compiler). Octave has a [NURBS package](http://octave.sourceforge.net/nurbs/), which I've not used before and I think R has a fairly comprehensive one too.

If you're arriving at this point from a probabilistic approach then something like "mixture of Gaussian" using an [EM 'like' algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation-maximization_algorithm) or ['Kriging'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriging) might make more sense.

Comment: For your second paragraph, a relevant term to be put into google is "Kriging". It is not really EM on a mixture of gaussians, it is instead a Bayesian fit of a Gaussian process. This is quite popular an approach among geophysicists.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'd not come across that term before, looks like there might be some useful references from that for me too!

Comment: This looks like what I need. Are there any ready implementations to play with?

Comment: yeah, kriging is great, and also works well in large dimensions. The only drawback is its complexity (O(n_points^3) iirc), so you may want to limit the number of points you give to it.

Comment: @user536232: I believe R has packages to deal with kriging.

Answer (score 0):

So you have the function values at set intervals like (0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1),etc..?
I don't think there's any 'best' way to approximate the values in between. You say the functions is 'smooth', so averaging the surrounding values might be nice.

Given a grid with point intervals (xInterval,yInterval); x going right and y going up;
I'd say something like this:

```
public void setAverage(float y, float x) {
    float dy = (y - yBottom)/yInterval;
    float leftAvgr = leftTopValue * dy + leftBottomValue * (1-dy);
    float rightAvrg = rightTopValue * dy + rightBottomValue * (1-dy);
    float dx = (x - xLeft)/xInterval;
    float avrg = rightAvrg * dx + leftAvgr * (1 - dx);
}
```

Comment: This is called bilinear interpolation, and might be too crude for OP.